# Rxjs filter a composable stream based on another stream

Tags: javascript, angular, rxjs

I have an array of `cars` that have properties:

```
cars: <Car[]> = [
    {
        color: 'red',
        make: 'mazda',
        year: 1960
    },
    {
        color: 'blue',
        make: 'mazda',
        year: 1984
    },
    {
        color: 'red',
        make: 'honda',
        year: 1999
    }
]
```

The observable `updatesToCars` is being modified and assigned to another observable `carsObservable`  via `.scan` and `.cache`.

```
let initialCars = cars;
carsObservable = updatesToCars.scan(
    (cars: Car[], operation /* some crud operation that modifies the cars array */) => {
        return operation(cars);
    }, initialCars
).cache();
```

`carsObservable` now has the most up to date list of cars. Cool! Let's now say I want to filter for all the cars that are of a certain make, whilst keeping composability in mind:

```
carsOfACertainMake = new BehaviorSubject('mazda');
filteredCarsOfACertainMake = carsOfACertainMake.map((make) => {
    return carsObservable.map((cars) => {
        return _.filter(cars, function(car) {
            return car.make === make;
        });
    });
}).switch().cache();
```

Now we can `carsOfACertainMake.next('honda')` and the `filteredCarsOfACertainMake` observable will only reflect cars that have the make value of `honda`.

We essentially have to empty out the `filteredCarsOfACertainMake` observable every time the need to filter by a different make is requested.

This works, but seems like a strange way to implement such functionality. Can the `.filter` observable achieve this instead? And if so, what is the required code?

Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you are looking for either `combineLatest` or `withLatestFrom`

```
var carsOfACertainMake = new BehaviorSubject('mazda');
carsObservable.withLatestFrom(carsOfACertainMake, (cars, make) =>
  _.filter(cars, car => car.make === make)
).cache();
```

`filter` is not going to help you very much in this situation because it can't really handle the case of a mutating criteria. Instead `withLatestFrom` will avoid the resubscription cost from above and will always emit with the latest filter set each time `carsObservable` emits.

Comment: Hi! This actually didn't work, but ```combineLatest``` did. Thanks a bunch!